# How to bind Bootstrap validation to dynamically added tags (select, input, etc.)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding new set of input tags (text and select tags) dynamically using AJAX: getting the file using AJAX and appending it to the current page.

How can I dynamically bind Bootstrap validation to each input properly?

Comment: https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/issues/125

Comment: What are you using to validate the inputs?